# assignment in init during property decorator use in python

Tags: python, decorator

I was trying to learn @property in python. I just wrote an example:

```
class sample(object):
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.x=a   ---> why is this assignment mandatory here?, I tried without and fail
    @property
    def x(self):
        print "getter"
        return self.__x
    @x.setter
    def x(self,a):
        print "setter"
        if a<=100 and a>=0:
           self.__x=a
        elif a<0:
           self.__x=0
        else:
           self.__x=100


ob=sample(30)
print ob.x
```

1)  Why the self.x=a in init is needed in this case?

2)In this example, whats the significance of public 'x'  here? I know its for encapsulation, but is this variable  'x' is a member of class now? OR class is only having  private variable __x?

Thanks!

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you retrieve the value of `x` without setting it first?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/syam.mohan/PycharmProjects/untitled2/TEST/qqq.py", line 31, in <module>
    print ob.x
  File "/Users/syam.mohan/PycharmProjects/untitled2/TEST/qqq.py", line 15, in x
    return self.__x
AttributeError: 'sample' object has no attribute '_sample__x'

Comment: Yes. Why does that surprise you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The public `x` is a function (actually, two). It overrides the actual variable assignment. So, if you have properties, when you do

```
obj.x = 5
```

it is equivalent of calling the `@x.setter` function  with a value of 5. Similarly, when you use `obj.x`, instead it calls the `obj.x()` property.
The actual variable is the "private" `self.__x`.

So, in general, the first assignment is not "needed". But, in this particular case, when you call `print(obj.x)`, the corresponding property tries to find `obj.__x`, which does not exist yet. But, if you make the assignment `self.x = 30` in the first line, it calls the `@x.setter` function with argument 30. This function creates the `self.__x` variable, so it now exists, and it can be correctly used by the getter when you `print(obj.x)`

Note: by the way, prefer `_x` (single underscore) for you private variable. Double underscore has special meaning